# RestSharp compress request while making rest call to server

Tags: .net, rest, restsharp

I am consuming a rest api written in java in my C# client. I was pumping hell lot of data to server and I was using RestSharp.dll for the purpose of making rest calls. What I will do is construct an object and add that directly in body of RestSharp request object and mention .netserializer for it. So it will automatically serialize it and post it. All works great.

Now I need to apply LZO or GZIP compression. So that server will have less load.

I know how to implement both compression techniques. But how to implement it with RestSharp request object?

What I got to do. I am adding object to body of request. When to perform compression?

Anyhelp...

Thanks

Comment: Why implement it at all? HTTP compression is routinely handled by the server and the client. You don't need to implement it yourself. HTTP compression is a feature of IIS and can be controlled on the client using the HttpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression property

Comment: I am using RestSharp. The data I am sending is huge. So I am even doing sometime 2X compression.

Comment: We have to set that property I think. Its not automatic. Anyhow Normal compression will not work out in my case. I have to compress it using Gzip or LZO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting GZip content using RestSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747595/posting-gzip-content-using-restsharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RestSharp [supports HTTP compression](http://www.bevanblackie.com/2012/03/restsharp-supports-gzip.html) since version 102.7. I'm not sure if this works only for Windows Phone or compression is supported for all platforms.

The most common algorithms are GZip and Deflate, although the actual level of compression is usually controlled by the server.

**UPDATE:**

I just verified using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) that HTTP Compression is enabled by default in 103.1. The following code returns a page encoded using GZip:

```
        var target = "http://msdn.microsoft.com/";
        var client=new RestClient(target);
        var request = new RestRequest("",Method.GET);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

There is no need to add the Accept-Encoding header.

Compression will only work if the server supports it. Otherwise the response will be uncompressed.

This means that the Java service will have to enable HTTP compression as well.

If the response is compressed the Content-Encoding header will be set to the compression method, eg. *gzip*.

To check this visually, open Fiddler and check the responce to the RestRequest. The Transformer tab of the Response pane displays the compression settings.

Comment: ok...if we add this request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip") in request object and post to server will it actually compress object using GZip. Ok after reading your link I think it do compress it.

Comment: I have enabled it and its posting data successfully after adding this as header. But now how can I verify that its really compressing things and posting to server.

Comment: Old question, but I feel like this answer is only asserting that RestSharp supports automatically **recieving** gzipped encodings. The question is most definitely about **sending** gzipped encoded data (automatically). I can confirm that even if I add a `"Content-Encoding", "gzip"` header to my `request` object, RestSharp ignores it and encodes the request body as UTF8. When sending large request bodies, it would be great if it could automatically compress serialized data to "gzip" upon request. Is this capability hidden within RestSharp anywhere?

Comment: @Alain HTTP only supports compressed *responses*. Compressed requests are part of HTTP/2 I think. No library can provide what isn't available in the protocol.

Comment: I did not know that! Thanks for the information. So if our API requires so much data transmission from the user that request compression is desirable, all parties should presumably implement it themselves?

In your opinion, is the most correct thing to do to set the "Content-Type" as "application/json" and set the "Content-Encoding" to "gzip" (and then encode it ourselves) - or should we be setting the "Content-Type" itself to "application/gzip" to avoid interference? (or some other header like "Transfer-Encoding")?