# How to get RestSharp to properly deflate compressed HTTP response?

Tags: c#, http, restsharp, compression

I'm using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to make a call to REST service. My call looks something like this:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/foo", Method.POST);
request.JsonSerializer.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.AddJsonBody(new string[] { "param1", "param2" });
var response = this._client.Execute<Foo>(request);
```

For most other calls this works fine. I'm running into issues when the response is compressed. The headers in the response look (mostly) like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Uncompressed-Size: 35000
Content-Length: 3019
Content-Encoding: deflate
Content-Type: application/json
```

The issue is when I call this method with RestSharp I keep getting the error:

> Error: Block length does not match with its complement.

I've tried setting the `Accept-Encoding` header in the request but it still produces the error. I also tried using a custom deserializer but the error is occurring before deserialization. From what I can tell, RestSharp should automatically handle deflation if the `Content-Encoding` header says `deflate` (which it does).

How can I get RestSharp to handle the deflation properly?

**UPDATE**

In the end I was able to have the service changed to look for an `Accept-Encoding` header in the request with a value of `identity`. If found, the service was changed to return the data uncompressed.

This is unfortunately not really a solution to the original issue but it does resolve the problem for me. If a better solution is posted I will try it.

Comment: Ever find a better solution for this? I'm hitting the same issue calling an API I don't have control over.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, you should be able to handle it if you won't pass charset=utf-8 in content type.

Please refer to this:
[RestSharp compress request while making rest call to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914672/restsharp-compress-request-while-making-rest-call-to-server)

Comment: I tried changing the ContentType in the request to this but it's still giving me the error: `request.JsonSerializer.ContentType = "application/json";`.

Comment: Try not to send the content type at all

Comment: Tried that but unfortunately it still didn't help.